# getting 0 instead of NaN (Matlab prog)

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab version 2011a, I am encountering a problem when I am trying to replace my missing values with NaN.. whereas the output is showing the replaced values as 0 instead of NaN. can I get a solution for that?

Comment: Please post your code and/or an example of the problem, and I will help you. Are you using cell arrays where the missing values are empty cells?

Comment: Dear JCKaz, suppose my dataset is:                                                                             RF=[12 13 15, -8888 12 16,-8888 19 17]                                                                   now I want to replace d -8888 by NaN and not 0(zero), for that my code is   RF(RF==-8888)=NaN;                                                                                          the output is coming as                                                                       RF=[12 13 15, 0 12 16,0 19 17]

Comment: Very strange, I copy-paste your code and I get your desired result:
´RF =

    12    13    15   NaN    12    16   NaN    19    17´

Comment: :( i donno y its not working in my machine.. which version of matlab u r using..though i think its a basic thing nothing to do with version.        anyways...Thank you so much

Comment: Perhaps you are right, I'm not sure. I am using 2015b. I am sure it has worked the past few years at least.

Comment: Thanks JCK.. Good Luck!

Comment: try casting RF into double. write: RF = double(RF) before replacing the values with nans. did it work?

Comment: oh thanq so much..it did worked!!

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought that you want to replace Nan values with zeros.
After reading your further explanation, I now understand that you don't want Matlab to automatically replace NaN values with zeros.

in order to do so, convert your array to double.
example:

```
%int version
RF=int16([12 13 15, -8888 12 16,-8888 19 17]);
RF(RF==-8888) = NaN;
RF

%double version
RF=double([12 13 15, -8888 12 16,-8888 19 17]);
RF(RF==-8888) = NaN;
RF
```

result for first caes:

```
RF =

 12     13     15      0     12     16      0     19     17
```

result for second caes:

```
RF =

12    13    15   NaN    12    16   NaN    19    17
```

**my previous answer:**

in order to replace NAN values with zeros, use MATLAB's isnan function.

however - I suggest to make further checking, in order to find out why did you get these Nan value in the first place - make sure that it's not a bug or a problem with the algorithm.

example for using isnan function:

```
%defines a matrix
A = rand(5,5);
%adds Nan values to it
A([1,6,8,10,15]) = nan;
%prints original A
A

%replacing Nans with zeros
A(isnan(A)) = 0;

%printing A after cleaning
A
```

result before:

```
A =

   NaN        NaN      0.9569    0.0530    0.4177
   0.7890    0.9077    0.1857    0.1554    0.6669
   0.6803       NaN    0.9870    0.6251    0.1863
   0.7103    0.9899    0.7671    0.3099    0.8293
   0.3857       NaN       NaN    0.6623    0.7091
```

result after:

```
A=

0         0         0.9569    0.0530    0.4177
0.7890    0.9077    0.1857    0.1554    0.6669
0.6803         0    0.9870    0.6251    0.1863
0.7103    0.9899    0.7671    0.3099    0.8293
0.3857         0         0    0.6623    0.7091
```

Comment: I do not believe that this is what he is asking for...

Comment: ya exactly..it is not that..

Comment: if that's the case, please edit your question to contain all the relevant information which you added to your comments.
@Daniel - is it possible to unmark the question as duplicated?